# Fragment switching when clicked on a texview Android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I am trying to change the display on my android screen when you click on a `textview`. This `textview` is inside a tab which is inside a `tabhost`. I created a fragment which would overlay on top of this tab when you click on it but having issues doing.

In my main activity I got this code;

```
tabHost.getTabContentView().findViewById(R.id.currentMoney).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {  
            switch(v.getId()){
                case R.id.currentMoney:
                    android.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); 
                    transaction.replace(R.id.tab2, new OverviewFragment());   
                    transaction.commit();
            }
        }
    });
```

This is the code that I have in my overview java class

```
public class OverviewFragment extends Fragment {


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_tab_transactionhistory, container, false);
    }

}
```

What happens is when I run this home_tab_transactionhistory xml file comes up right underneath what ever I had before. Doesn't even show fully what ever I have got in the home_tab_transactionhistory xml file.

Below I have listed the xml code of the page that should take you to another page when you click on a text view;

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="#369742"
android:gravity="start|end"
android:longClickable="true">

<TabHost
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/tabHost"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:clickable="false">

<TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="270dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#5DAD68"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:measureWithLargestChild="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1.04"
            android:longClickable="false"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"></TabWidget>


<FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:clickable="false">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:weightSum="1">

<TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                            android:text="@string/currentMoney"
                            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                            android:onClick="showCurrentAccountMoney"
                            android:id="@+id/currentMoney"
                            android:paddingTop="5dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:textColor="#ff000000"
                            android:textSize="40dp" />
```

id of the textview is currentMoney

Please can someone help me fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should post the xml layout file where there is your clickable text view. To make the new Fragment overlay, you should add it to a FrameLayout which places its childs on top of each other.

Comment: I have added in the xml file, Sorry I am not sure what you said there

Comment: What i meant is that if your tab2 was a FrameLayout instead of a LinearLayout, the new Fragment would cover the TextView because the FrameLayout places his Childs on top of each other, so you can obtain the overlay in this way.